# Returning a list of child id's from parent in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, and I just couldn't figure out what to do. I have a parent element, and have six div elements in it. In javascript, I am trying to get an array of their id's. Here's the list:

```
<div id="everything">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to to make a javascript function that could list all of the child element id's in the parent element, and put them into an array. Is this possible. I apologize if this is a dumb fix, I am still getting the hang of things. Thank you!

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: `var ids = [].slice.call(document.getElementById("everything").children).map((q) => q.getAttribute("id"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the children of the parent div element into an array. Loop through the array and retrieve the id attribute of each one of them.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('everything').children
const idArray = Array.from(parent).map(x => x.id);

console.log(idArray)
```

```html
<div id="everything">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
</div>
```